# UISlider on Scrollview - Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I added a custom slider to my scrollview on my viewcontroller but after adding it I am unable to scroll. I have looked at similar questions on here but

```
scrollview.canCancelContentTouches=NO;
```

is not working. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Slider code:

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 12.0, 280.0, 480);
_customSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[_customSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
_customSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeslide.png"]
                            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:2.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider.png"]
                             stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:2.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

   [_customSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_customSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];

_customSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
_customSlider.maximumValue = 10.0;
_customSlider.continuous = YES;
_customSlider.value = 50.0;

[ _scrollview addSubview:_customSlider];
```

Comment: Tell us about the custom slider. What is it? How did you create it? Show code.

Comment: show your code that how your adding the slider in scroll view..

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect when you use the slider and stop use the scrollview.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600290/uislider-and-uiscrollview) can help